# PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted in Python while reading after write

Tags: python

I encountered following problem while writing my program: I have binary file, via which 2 processes are communicating, one of them is my python program. I open file with os:

```
self.io_file = os.open(med_file, os.O_RDWR)
```

so I can read it binary. I read content of the file, then try to write answer into the same file (I'm at the end of file, of course). Everything's alright up until I try to read again (new question) after this write. Then following happens:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ydenko/program.py", line 172, in read
return os.read(self.io_file, msg_size)
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

I find it curious that up until I write something, everything works flawlessly.
Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

- Check if you have write permission to that directory
- Check if the system is mounted in rw mode
- Also check lsattr if somebody has set the extended attributes

Comment: Thanks for help, already figured it out. The other program (sys daemon) was perpetually checking (once every 5s) if file is processed (e.g. read) and I was stupid enough to put 10s sleep in between write and next read. Still, it is unusual. I was ready for something like "bad file descriptor", not this.